# Rsyslog: how to negate 'contains' in if-then statement

Tags: rsyslog

```
if $programname == "service" then {
     if $msg !contains "test" then
         action(type="omfwd" 
            target="10.0.0.5"
            ...
            ) 
}
```

I'm trying to **exclude a msg if it contains word 'test'**. Not sure how to negate 'contains'.

From the [document](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html), it seems to be '!contains'. Tried it but no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax `!` for negation applies to legacy selectors of the form

```
:msg, !contains, "test"  /some/file
```

You are using RainerScript, so the appropriate syntax is the keyword `not`:

```
if not ($msg contains "test") then
```